# Is there a better way to retrieve unique ID upon INSERT?

Tags: sql-server, insert

I am using the following SQL Server statement to insert records and return the unique auto-inc ID value all in one shot. Wonder if there is a simpler/faster/better way to do it?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @res table (ID bigint);

INSERT INTO [Titles] ([Name],[Timestamp],[Title])
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @res
VALUES ('Name','23 aug 2010','this is a title');

SELECT [ID] FROM @res;
```

**UPD:** The solution that suits me best is the following:

```
INSERT INTO [TestCase] ([Name],[Tags],[Timestamp],[Title])
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
VALUES ('Hello',0x22324423,'23 aug 2010','this is a title');
```

Very code-generation friendly. You can easily generate these statements for any data structure through reflection. Also works very well as a substitute for `Linq2SQL Dataset.InsertOnSubmit()`.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481395/t-sql-identity-scope-identity-output-and-other-methods-of-retrieving-last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler:

```
INSERT INTO [Titles] ([Name],[Timestamp],[Title]) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES ('Name','23 aug 2010','this is a title');
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using @@Identity

```
INSERT INTO Production.Location (Name, CostRate, Availability, ModifiedDate)
VALUES ('Damaged Goods', 5, 2.5, GETDATE());
GO
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';
```

for more information check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY.

See also answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481395/t-sql-identity-scope-identity-output-and-other-methods-of-retrieving-last).