# Scope_Identity() returning incorrect value fixed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, nhibernate

I've been searching hi and low for an answer to this and figured I would turn to the stackoverflow community. I have been avoiding using type identity id fields fields within sql server and nhibernate due to this bug:  http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value

However, I just noticed that it was marked as fixed.

Does, anybody know if this applies to the recent SQL server service pack that was released? I can't find a yes or no to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to try the query and test your results. There are a number of work arounds on this such as Output clause and run query not in parralel.

See Microsoft KB on this 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779

Also a post on this that indicated not sure if fixed in 2008 SP1 but may be fixed in 2008 R2

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/24/sql-server-2008-scope_identity-bug-with-multi-processor-parallel-plan-and-solution/

Comment: Thanks Justin, while I'm aware of the work around's still haven't found the definite yes or no....this ages old bug has been fixed.

Comment: It's unbelievable that such a bug ever existed.  Wow.  This bug is the equivalent of one saying "The 'select' statement sometimes returns the wrong rows, like if you run more than one query at once."  Renders the entire database engine non-functional.  Sad.