# Should I always use 'implicit_returning':False in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

What's the potential pitfall of always using `'implicit_returning': False` in SQLAlchemy?

I've encountered problems a number of times when working on MSSQL tables that have triggers defined, and since the DB is in replication, all of the tables have triggers.

I'm not sure now what the problem exactly is. It has something to do with auto-increment fields - maybe because I'm prefetching the auto-incremented value so I can insert it in another table.

If I don't set `'implicit_returning': False` for the table, when I try to insert values, I get this error:

> The target table of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers
>   if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

So what if I put `__table_args__ = {'implicit_returning': False}` into all mapped classes just to be safe?

Particularly frustrating for me is that local DB I use for development & testing is not in replication and doesn't need that option, but the production DB is replicated so when I deploy changes they sometimes don't work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably already know, the cause of your predicament is described in [SQLAlchemy Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html?highlight=__mapper_args__#triggers) as the following:

> SQLAlchemy by default uses `OUTPUT INSERTED` to get at newly generated
>   primary key values via `IDENTITY` columns or other server side
>   defaults. MS-SQL does not allow the usage of `OUTPUT INSERTED` on
>   tables that have triggers. To disable the usage of `OUTPUT INSERTED`
>   on a per-table basis, specify `implicit_returning=False` for each
>   Table which has triggers.

If you set your SQLAlchemy engine to echo the SQL, you will see that by default, it does this:

```
INSERT INTO [table] (id, ...) OUTPUT inserted.[id] VALUES (...)
```

But if you disable `implicit_returning`, it does this instead:

```
INSERT INTO [table] (id, ...) VALUES (...); select scope_identity()
```

So the question, "Is there any harm in disabling `implicit_returning` for all tables just in case?" is really, "Is there any disadvantage to using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `OUTPUT INSERTED`?"

I'm no expert, but I get the impression that although `OUTPUT INSERTED` is the preferred method these days, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is usually fine too.  In the past, SQL Server 2008 (and maybe earlier versions too?) had a bug where `SCOPE_IDENTITY` sometimes didn't return the correct value, but I hear that has now been fixed ([see this question for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562917/scope-identity-returning-incorrect-value-fixed)).  (On the other hand, other techniques like `@@IDENTITY` and `IDENT_CURRENT()` are still dangerous since they can return the wrong value in corner cases. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/481445/5405967) and the others on that same page for more detail.)

The big advantage that `OUTPUT INSERTED` still has is that it can work for cases where you are inserting multiple rows via a single `INSERT` statement.  Is that something you are doing with SQLAlchemy?  Probably not, right? So it doesn't matter.

Note that if you are going to have to disable `implicit_returning` for many tables, you could avoid a bit of boilerplate by making a mixin for it (and whichever other columns and properties you want all of the tables to inherit):

```
class AutoincTriggerMixin():
    __table_args__ = {
        'implicit_returning': False
    }

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

class SomeModel(AutoincTriggerMixin, Base):
    some_column = Column(String(1000))
    ...
```

See [this page in the SQLALchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html) for more detail.  As an added bonus, it makes it more obvious which tables involve triggers.