# Scope_Identity in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure which has 3 insert statements. What I need is after each insert I want to know the inserted value of the ID by querying `Scope_Identity`.

Something like following :

```
insert into t1(name)values("david")
set @v1=Scope_Identity()

insert into t2(name)values("david2")
set @v2=Scope_Identity()

insert into t3(name)values("david3")
set @v4=Scope_Identity()
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? If not, in what way didn't it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481395/t-sql-identity-scope-identity-output-and-other-methods-of-retrieving-last

Comment: yes but it store nothing in variables

Comment: Well, you've not shown enough for us to diagnose the issue, just from the above. The above code should work and `@v1`, `@v2` and `@v4` should contain values. (Not sure why `@v3` never appeared :-))

Comment: [Looks like it is working here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8aeb/1)

Comment: @franchescototti Are you sure the tables have `identity` column ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id int identity, name varchar(30))
CREATE TABLE t2 (id int identity, name varchar(30))

DECLARE @v1 int, @v2 int

INSERT t1 (name) VALUES ('david')
SET @v1 = Scope_Identity()

INSERT t2 (name) VALUES ('david2')
SET @v2 = Scope_Identity()

SELECT @v1, @v2
```

Click [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b465/1) to see it in action at SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , name VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.id
VALUES ('test1'), ('test2')
```