# How I can get an auto incremented value

Tags: sql, pdo

I have here a table that corresponds to the orders of the customers. I use `AUTO_INCREMENT` to determine the ID of the order. I have this SQL code to the `orders` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `order_total_price` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

What I need is to insert each of the products of that order in another table with a Foreign Key `order_id` to specify what order that products belongs to. The SQL code for the `purchased_products` table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `purchased_products` (
  `order_id` int (11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES orders(`order_id`),
  `product_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `product_price` decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL,
  `product_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
)
```

When the user buy something, I use this to insert the data in the `orders` table:

```
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, customer_name, order_total_price, order_date)
VALUES ('{$customer_id}', '{$customer['customer_name']}', '{$order_total_price}', '{$order_date}')";
```

And here is my problem. I need to insert in the `purchased_products` table the products with the Order ID generated:

```
INSERT INTO purchased_products (order_id, product_name, product_price, product_quantity)
VALUES ('*/The ID of the order need to goes here*/', '{$product['product_name']}', '{$product['product_price']}', '{$product['quantity']}')";
```

This is giving me a headache. I'm not really knowing how to do it. This should be done by a different way? How do I associate the order ID to the products belonging to it?

Comment: There are ways to determine "just assigned" auto-ids, but pretty much each RDBMS has their own methods. Thus, the standard question: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Just a suggestion .. use `MAX()` method.. This will figure out the last inserted `id` .. But note that this will help only if no other `insert` has been done on the orders table .. This is just a way

Comment: The RDBMS knows what was the last inserted auto incremented id into the particular table. You can get it. In mysql it is called LAST_INSERT_ID as far as I remember. However, as @Philip Kelley mentioned it depends on the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: fwiw, postgres sql supports the returning keyword, so you would add **returning order_id** at the end of your *<insert into order>*.  But this is mysql and this question would benefit greatly by the use of the **mysql** tag.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. Without you I would not have been able to solve the problem. I've posted an answer with my own solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by using PDO `lastInsertId()` to get the ID of last inserted order:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, customer_name, order_total_price, order_date)
        VALUES ('{$customer_id}', '{$customer['customer_name']}', '{$order_total_price}', '{$order_date}')";

$query = $connection->prepare($sql);    
$query->execute();

$respective_order_id = $connection->lastInsertId();
```

And then:

```
INSERT INTO purchased_products (order_id, product_name, product_price, product_quantity)
VALUES ('{$respective_order_id}', '{$product['product_name']}', '{$product['product_price']}', '{$product['quantity']}')";
```

Thanks for all who tried to help! They put me in the right way!

Answer (score 1):

use function [`last_insert_id()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). it will give you value that was auto-incremented as last one before call to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the get the last inserted primary key value by using `@@IDENTITY`

Here's the MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
--Display the value of LocationID in the last row in the table.
SELECT MAX(LocationID) FROM Production.Location;
GO
INSERT INTO Production.Location (Name, CostRate, Availability, ModifiedDate)
VALUES ('Damaged Goods', 5, 2.5, GETDATE());
GO

SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';
GO
--Display the value of LocationID of the newly inserted row.
SELECT MAX(LocationID) FROM Production.Location;
GO
```

I would also recommend wrapping the statement in a `TRANSACTION` so that if any errors occur you can rollback.

Comment: But I need to get the last primary key value from the table `orders` and then add it to `oder_id` in `purchased_products` table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to retrieve the last identity you inserted within the current sql session.

here is another question with a great description of all the differences:

[identity scope Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481395/identity-scope-identity-output-and-other-methods-of-retrieving-last-identi)

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented it depends on the RDBMS. In Oracle you typically use [sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF51138). You create and store the sequence on the database and can use it on an `INSERT` by doing `sequencename.nextval()`.

Sequences let you control starting values, increment/decrement size, caching and a lot more.