# What is scope in SQL Server / how is it defined?

Tags: sql-server

*I am trying to find documentation on SQL Server where concept of scope is defined. I just want to understand it better.*

I had been looking at `scope_identity()` function and it says that `@@identity` result and `scope_identity()` result will differ in case there are triggers defined which insert records into another table with an identity column.

It seems `scope_identity()` decides that insert in the trigger is in different scope. I want to see how that is determined/where it is documented...

Comment: Or https://www.google.co.uk/#q=what+is+scope+in+sql+server+

Comment: Hmm. I did, I wasn't asking about those functions (scope_identity() /@@identity). was asking about concept of scope , which I thought might be documented on its own somewhere...

Comment: possible duplicate of [@@IDENTITY, SCOPE\_IDENTITY(), OUTPUT and other methods of retrieving last identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481395/identity-scope-identity-output-and-other-methods-of-retrieving-last-identi)

Comment: I wish people who felt the need to respond to questions with "search Google" would recognize that SO is indeed indexed by Google. For example, this page is the *first* one that comes up when Googling "SQL Server Scope".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch.
>   Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the
>   same stored procedure, function, or batch.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx