# problem using OUTPUT parameter insetad of SCOPE_IDENTITY

Tags: sql, asp.net, t-sql, webforms, ado.net

I am trying to use `OUTPUT` param instead of `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in my query. I have gone through some resources but couldn't understand how to use it.
For example I am adding my existing code.

```
protected string Test(DataRow dataRow, out QueryParamList paramList)
    {
        paramList = new QueryParamList();

        StringBuilder sqlBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sqlBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataRow.ItemArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!IsPrimaryKey(dataRow, i))
            {
                if (dataRow.ItemArray[i] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    sqlBuilder1.Append(dataRow.Table.Columns[i].Caption + ",");
                    sqlBuilder2.Append("@" + dataRow.Table.Columns[i].Caption + ",");
                    DbType dbType = (DbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(DbType), dataRow.Table.Columns[i].DataType.Name);
                    paramList.Add(new QueryParamObj() { ParamName = dataRow.Table.Columns[i].Caption, ParamValue = dataRow.ItemArray[i], DBType = dbType });
                }
            }
        }
        if (sqlBuilder1.Length > 0) sqlBuilder1.Remove(sqlBuilder1.Length - 1, 1);
        if (sqlBuilder2.Length > 0) sqlBuilder2.Remove(sqlBuilder2.Length - 1, 1);

        string finalQuery = "Insert Into " + dataRow.Table.TableName + "(" + sqlBuilder1.ToString() + ")" + " values(" + sqlBuilder2.ToString() + ");select SCOPE_IDENTITY()";


        return finalQuery;
    }
```

Here in `finalQuery` I want to make change.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Using OUTPUT INTO with a simple INSERT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-output-into-with-a-simple-insert-statement) you can follow this pattern:

```
INSERT INTO TableName(..,..)
OUTPUT INSERTED...
VALUES (.., .., ..)
```

So, in your case this should work(Assuming your identity column is `ID`):

```
string finalQuery = "Insert Into " + dataRow.Table.TableName + "(" + sqlBuilder1.ToString() + ")" + " OUTPUT INSERTED.ID "+ " values(" + sqlBuilder2.ToString() + ");";
```

See also [IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), OUTPUT and other methods of retrieving last identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481395/identity-scope-identity-output-and-other-methods-of-retrieving-last-identi)