# Related tables inserting data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a little question.

Short description of the project: I'm working on a little API project written in C#. Inside this project I'm using the onion architecture, in short it's something like Controller -> Service -> Repository.

I have an Account controller, which manages create & update User and beside this I have a databas ewith the following tables:

```
User, Password, UserInformation
```

In `User` I have the following columns: Id(PK), userName and role.

In `Password` I have: User_Id(PK and FK to User - Id column), password and oldPassword (if necessary).

In `UserInformation` I have: User_Id(PK and FK to User - Id column), firstName, lastName and email.

As for inserting data, I have a separate class with string constants inside which are queries and I'm executing them by doing

```
sqlConnection.QueryAsync(QueryFromStringConstants, etcParams).
```

As I'm a little bit noobish with the SQL syntax and everything related to SQL in general(haha), my question is: if I create a `User`, how can I insert data into all 3 tables at the same time?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Primary Key on your `User` table is an `int` or `bigint`, you use the function `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get the PK.

```sql
set nocount, xact_abort on;   --recommended

begin transaction;

insert into user(User_Id,userName,...)
values(...);

declare @user_id int = scope_identity();   -- make sure this is the very next line after insert

insert into Password(User_Id,....)
values(@user_id,...);

insert into UserInformation(User_Id,....)
values(@user_id,...);

commit transaction;
```

If you are doing a multi-row insert, you can use Table-Valued Parameters. And then you will need the `OUTPUT` clause to output the IDs into a new table variable:

```sql
set nocount, xact_abort on;   --recommended

begin transaction;

declare @new_users table (user_id int, username varchar(50));

insert into user(User_Id,userName,...)
output inserted.user_id, inserted.username
select ...
from @users;

insert into Password(User_Id,....)
select u.user_id, ...
from passwords p
join @new_users u on u.username = p.username;

commit transaction;
```

---

I must say though, that I don't see the point in having a separate table for `UserInformation`, after all, you cannot have a `User` without `UserInformation`, so you shouold combine these into one.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer :D
As it is right now, is the query affected if I'm using Microsoft SQL Manager Studio with SQL Server? 
Also, it seems that when I created my tables (with a schema) they got created into System Databases - Master part... It seems a bit weird as it won't let me access the tables. I tried:
master.users, master.schema.users, users ... do you have any ideea as to how am I supposed to access the tables?

Comment: Don't know, do you have permissions on `master`? Try `USE master;` then just access the tables straight. SSMS: you can still use that, just declare your variables first (instead of parameters) then run the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Each insert requires a separate insert statement, and you should also get an identity value after each insert in order to use it for next insert, for example:

1. insert user: `INSERT INTO User (userName, role) VALUES (...)`
2. get user Id (I'm sure you definded it as IDENTITY): `DECLARE @userId AS integer = (SELECT @@IDENTITY);`
3. insert user password (with user id obtained on prevoius step)
4. insert user info (the same)

But you can also use Entity framework. You should create class `User`, which have virtual properties of type `Password` and `UserInformation` (also classes you should create as well). Then create a context which has a property `DbSet<User> Users`. In this case you just create a User instance, populate its fields, Password and UserInformation with correspondent instances of Password and UserInformation classes. Then use:

```
context.Users.Add(userInstanceVar);
context.SaveChanges();
```

That's all! EF will save all instances into your database, and also populates all identity values automatically.

Comment: [`@@IDENTITY` has issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481395/identity-scope-identity-output-and-other-methods-of-retrieving-last-identi), use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` instead

Comment: @Charlieface Hmmm, cool, I didn't know about this issue. They also recomment to use OUTPUT instead)). However I think it's a good point to start from))

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer :D. I will take that into account for my future projects. For now I chose to learn how to "play" with Dapper.

Answer (score -1):

You have to insert in the primary table then into the others.
and use transaction to run the three statements.
the following is an example using oracle procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE InsertUser(.. params ...) 
as 
temp_id number;
BEGIN
insert into user(User_Id,userName,...) values(...) returning User_Id into temp_id;
insert into Password(User_Id,....) values(temp_id,...);
insert into UserInformation(User_Id,....) values(temp_id,...);
commit;
exception when others then rollback;
END InsertUser;
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid / proper T-SQL syntax for SQL Server (which the question is for)

Comment: correct as the sql type was not specified I answered with oracle sql not sql server. other answers provided proper sql server syntax.

Comment: You welcome. sorry that the syntax was not what you needed.